# Do I need the .cue file to play ps1 games on epsxe

Tags: emulation, ps1, epsxe

I have been emulating ps1 for a while now so I don't ruin my cds, but I have always kept both the .bin and the .cue. Do I need the .cue or can I just use the .bin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most, if not all, PSX games discs only have a single data track, which makes .cue files totally pointless for PSX game images. If your .cue files contain only the following, then you are free to delete them; if they contain more than a single track record, or the index is not 00:00:00, then you should keep them.

```
FILE "whatever.bin" BINARY
  TRACK 01 MODE2/2352
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you should as well keep all files, it s not like they will take a lot of space (72o each...)